# Capture File Details of all subjobs in Talend

Tags: talend, data-capture

I have a requirement to move files from SFTP to a local directory and it is simple.
I have used 
`tftpconnection-->tfileexists-->(if)tfileinput-->tmap--tfileoutput` to move files and then i have other subjobs as `tfileexists-->(if)tfileinput-->tmap--tfileoutput`. 
I have ten subjobs in the same job moving different files from different directories of SFTP.

I have to also capture all the file related details i.e size of file, number of rows and time of processing, source and destination.

Now i guess i can achieve this if i use

```
tfileproperties--->iterate--->tfilerowcount--->onComponentOk--->tfixedFlowInput
-- tfileoutput
```

However I just want one subjob that can capture all the details of the files.But in the above flow i have to hard code subjob file details i want to capture in the tfixedFlowInput which is not what i am looking for. Is there any way i can make this happen in a single subjob by dynamically changing file details in tFixedFlowInput.

Any guidance will be great-full.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choice:

- You can use the component tFileProperties (or tFTPFilePropertie).
- You can use intern variable of the component tFileinput ( Windows -> Show view -> General -> Structure -> Your Component )

PS : If you just want to only move file without do any modifications you can use tfilecopy maybe.

Comment: I am using tmap as i am doing some transformations on the data.
Also, I have used tFileProperties, but in that i have to create the tFileProperties flow for all the sub jobs. Is there a way i can capture file details of all the subjobs in a in a single flow. Lastly i was not able to find your Structure under General.